# Неправильный порядок элементов в задании

Tags: html

Я начал проходить задание

> Task: after the heading, create a paragraph with the Cities of England: text. Below, create an unordered list with three items: London, Birmingham, Manchester. Next, add another paragraph with the Cities of Italy:, after which create an ordered list with four elements: Rome, Florence, Naples, Venice.

Я написал такой код к нему:

```html
<body>
  <p>Cities of England:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>London</li>
    <li>Birmingham</li>
    <li>Manchester</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Cities of Italy:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Florence</li>
    <li>Rome</li>
    <li>Naples</li>
    <li>Venice</li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

Но в результате пишет:

```
InvalidOutput   Task is done incorrectly: invalid order of elements
```

Скажите пожалуйста что надо исправить.

Comment: ты всё перепутал. надо в первом списке - неупорядоченные, во втором- упорядоченные

Comment: правда не ясно что такое heading..... возможно `<h1></h1>`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Возможно Вам действительно нужно поменять элементы местами, как это указал @Beka .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li>Rome</li>
<li>Florence</li>
<li>Naples</li>
<li>Venice</li>
```